# Login Hive, log4j file

Tags: hadoop, hive, fiware, cosmos

I'm trying to access to Hive by the command window.
I just run "Hive" in the appropiate directory but I get an error "Login denied".
I've read that log4j is used to log in, but I don't know whether I have to create an account and write my user data there or not.
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you set the HIVE_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Yes, Rengasami, HIVE_HOME and JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

The Hive service should be working right now. From a FI-LAB VM of your own, you simply have to log into the Head Node using your Cosmos credentials (if you have no Cosmos credentials, get them by registering [here](http://cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org/cosmos-gui/)):

```
[root@your_filab_vm]$ssh cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org
```

Once logged in the Head Node, type the following command:

```
[your_cosmos_username@cosmosmaster-gi]$ hive
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive-0.9.0-shark-0.8.0-bin/lib/hive-common-0.9.0-shark-0.8.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/<your_cosmos_username>/hive_job_log_<your_cosmos_username>_201407212017_1797291774.txt
hive>
```

As you can see, in this example your Hive history will be written within:

```
/tmp/<your_cosmos_username>/hive_job_log_<your_cosmos_username>_201407212017_1797291774.txt
```